# Display content from a specific category using cat ID not working

Tags: categories, blog

OK I'm a bit hopeless at this, but I'm trying to get my news page (template theme) to display content from one category only (ID 1) but I cant seem to get it to work. Instead of just displaying posts from category 1 it displays posts from all category's.

I've got the working code below, how do I amend this to show a certain category?  I've tried using WP_Query but I can't have been doing it right.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area"> 
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

        <?php
        endif;

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

        the_posts_pagination();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a custom template you would need to use WP-Query to filter out posts for just one category:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'cat' => '12' // Insert category ID here
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

So your code should read something like this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area"> 
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<?php
$args = array(
'cat' => '12' // Insert category ID here
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : //loop for custom query ?>

 <header>
<h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?> </h1>   
 </header>

    /* Start the Loop */
   <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        /*
         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;

    the_posts_pagination();

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif; ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Your welcome, there are many ways to query wordpress for categories and almost anything in your database! Have a read here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query